# Solve an equation involving a convex function

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a twice differentiable function with $f''(x)>0$. Solve the following equation in $\mathbb{R}$:
$$f(2x+4)-f(2x+1)=f(x+3)-f(x+1).$$

I am stuck in this problem.

I sense that the mean value theorem could be useful.
I used $f(x)=x^2$ to see if it gives a nice solution (like $0$) but it gives that the only solution is $-\dfrac{7}{8}$.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are there special values of $x$ that cause terms to cancel.  For instance, $2x+4=x+3$ gives that $x = -1$ causes one term from each side to cancel.

Comment: I don't see how I could use that to solve the equation.

Comment: Oh I may have been misunderstood.
This is not a functional equation.
The problem is asking to find all x for which the equation holds.

Comment: what is the context of this problem ? what book did you get it from?

Comment: Ok, so the question is : given $f$ with all these constraints, what values of $x$ satisfy the above equation?